# Android - background color of selected items in ListView through selectors

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView and inside a DrawerLayout and the background is being applied through a selector, I have specified background color for selected item but that color is not being applied, A green color (no idea where its coming from, its not in my colors.xml or anywhere)

Here is what I have

menuitem_style.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@color/mainColor"/>
<!--mainColor is #4CAEE3-->
<item
    android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
```

The ListView:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@drawable/menuitem_style"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/white"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" />
```

related Java code

```
 mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
```

This is the outcome:

[image]

The mainColor is definitely blue and not green (#4CAEE3)
I am doing something wrong, not sure what. any help will be apprciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind the concept that in list views and recyclerview the views are recycled.

You can keep track the position of the current selected element:

```
 OnItemClickListener listViewOnItemClick = new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int position, long id) {
                mSelectedItem = position;
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
```

And override the getView method of your adapter:

```
   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_list, null);

        if (position == mSelectedItem) {
            // set your color
        }

        return view;
    }
```

For me it did the trick.

Comment: you are welcome to vote up my post if you like it :)

Comment: hey, do you know if this solution works for all of the android versions, it worked on android 5 but doesn't work on android 7

Comment: it is generic thing works on every api dear. nothing to do with api versions.

Answer (score 0):

Use this background as textview background rather listview background. Go to the row xml file you are using for list view populating and set the background there. Hope that helps you.

Comment: that changed the background of "Messages" to white forming a white box in green background list item

Answer (score 0):

```
   android:listSelector="@drawable/listitem_selector"

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/black"/>
        <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@color/gray"/>
    </selector>
```

try this one. It may help you.

Comment: the background turns black, in "press" state the background of whole list is gray but the selected item is still green